# Image segmentation with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, image-segmentation

I have been trying to perform image segmentation with raspberry Pi. I searched for different pre-trained models to perform it and came across tensorflow lite, it has a deeplab model in it, it is very less in size (2.7 Mb) and can be used for IOT devices. But in my case, I have a custom dataset and I need to train the model on my dataset (i.e training deeplab with custom dataset). My issue is raspberry Pi has less RAM and storage (comparatively). So, if I train deeplab with the custom dataset, can I run it on raspberry Pi. If so, is there any tutorial or a research paper about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/train.py) training script. Clone the [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) and run `model.py` from  `model/research/deeplab`.

I wouldn´t train the model on the Raspberry Pi, because it´s damn slow. A better approach would be to train it on a PC (maybe with GPU support) and export the model to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Does it predict in realtime in raspberry pi?

Comment: This depends on your input image (size, channels), the graph size, etc. You have to try it. Maybe you use the original model and test it on the Raspberry Pi. You can add some kind of accelerator device (i. e. an Edge TPU USB-Stick) to speed up the classification.